# How can I print the prime numbers ending with 1 in a given range and the nearest one after b?

Tags: java

- Sample input :
  10 
  100
- Sample output :
  11,31,41,61,71,101
- from the above code I can get the sample output value upto the value 71,how can I get nearest prime number ending with 1 after b.

Here is the code I tried:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=in.nextInt();
    int b=in.nextInt();
    int i,j,count;
    for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        for(j=2;j<=b;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            break;
        }
        if(j==i && j%10==1) 
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your choice of algorithm, but your outer loop stops at b, so it can never go higher.

Comment: Do you want all the primes from a to b including the first one after or just the first prime after b that ends with 1.

Comment: Roshni - Upvoting this question for the [improvement you have shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025768/to-print-prime-numbers-that-ends-with-1). You should always try first before posting a question and whenever you post the question, you should include whatever you have already tried. Wish you success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to divide a number by numbers up to it in order to check if it is prime. You just need to check up to its square root. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test. Do it as follows:

## Using a `for` loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter two integers separated by space: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int i, j, sqrt;

        // Note that there are three sections in the declaration of a 'for' loop:
        // for(initialization;condition;change) where none of the sections is
        // mandatory. There is no condition put in the loop syntax given below. The
        // condition for termination has been put after printing the prime number.
        for (i = a;; i++) {
            sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(i);
            for (j = 2; j <= sqrt; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If the loop with j completed without a break, the number is prime. Note that
            // 1 is not a prime number.Also, the last digit of the number should be 1.
            if (j > sqrt && Math.abs(i) != 1 && i % 10 == 1) {
                System.out.print(i + " "); // Print the prime
                if (i >= b) {// Condition for termination
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Alternatively, using a `while` loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter two integers separated by space: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int i = a, j, sqrt;

        while (true) {
            sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(i);
            for (j = 2; j <= sqrt; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If the loop with j completed without a break, the number is prime. Note that
            // 1 is not a prime number.Also, the last digit of the number should be 1.
            if (j > sqrt && Math.abs(i) != 1 && i % 10 == 1) {
                System.out.print(i + " "); // Print the prime
                if (i >= b) {// Condition for termination
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter two integers separated by space: 10 100
11 31 41 61 71 101
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter two integers separated by space: 10 200
11 31 41 61 71 101 131 151 181 191 211
```

Comment: Thank you sir, for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it, run the first loop indefinitely and break it when i is greater than b and it's a prime with 1 at the end.

This is the implementation just modifying your code a bit-

```
import java.util.*;
class Program{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=in.nextInt();
        int b=in.nextInt();
        boolean flag = false;
        int i,j,count;
        for(i=a;;i++) { 
            if(i>b) flag = true;
            for(j=2;j<=i;j++) {
                if(i%j==0)
                break;
            }
            if(j==i && j%10==1) {
                System.out.println(i);
                if(flag) break;     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add condition in both the for loops like I<= b*2;

After that before printing the series add one more if block or add the condition in if(j==1 && j%10==1)
Condition-
You should have to check what is value of i and whether it's greater than b or not. If it's greater than b then it should be end with 1 and nearer value otherwise no need to print and break it as other values you don't need at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a few improvements.

- first check to see if divisible by 2
- then, since 2 is taken care of, divide only by odd numbers
  starting with 3, not exceeding the sqrt of the number under test.
- then just continue until the search parameter are met.

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        outer:

        for (int i = a; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
          // first check division by 2 so you can increment by 2 later
          if (i % 2 == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            // increment from 3 to square root of i by 2's
            for (int j = 3; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j+=2) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    // not prime so continue with outer loop
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            if (i % 10 == 1) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                // keep searching until i > b.
                if (i > b) {
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
```

for input of `10 100` Prints

```
 11 31 41 61 71 101
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need a prime satisfying these conditions:

- within a range (lower to upper)
- ending in 1
- nearest to a query value

If so, wouldn't the best strategy be to search outwards in both directions (below and above) and stop when you first hit a prime ending in 1?

```
public static int nearest1Prime(final int lower, final int upper, final int val)
{
    if(val < lower || val > upper) return 0;

    int before, after;
    if((val % 10) == 1) 
    {
        if(isPrime(val))
            return val;
        before = val - 10;
        after = val + 10;
    }
    else
    {
        int base = 10 * (val / 10);
        if(val == base)
        {
            after = base+1;
            before = after-10;
        }
        else
        {
            before = base+1;
            after = before+10;
        }
    }

    int prime = 0;

    while(prime == 0 && (before >= lower || after <= upper))
    {
        if(before >= lower && isPrime(before)) 
            prime = before;

        if(after <= upper && isPrime(after) && (prime == 0 || (after-val) < (val-before)))
            prime = after;  

        before -= 10;
        after -= 10;
    }

    return prime;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int v)
{
    for(int i=(int)Math.sqrt(v); i>1; i--)
    {
        if((v % i) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Testing:

```
int lower = 10;
int upper = 100;

for(int i=lower; i<=upper; i++)
{
    int prime = nearest1Prime(lower, upper, i);
    System.out.println("Nearest Prime: " + i + " : " + prime);
}
```

Output:

```
10 : 11
11 : 11
12 : 11
13 : 11
14 : 11
15 : 11
16 : 11
17 : 11
18 : 11
19 : 11
20 : 11
21 : 11
22 : 31
23 : 31
24 : 31
25 : 31
26 : 31
27 : 31
28 : 31
29 : 31
30 : 31
31 : 31
32 : 31
33 : 31
34 : 31
35 : 31
36 : 31
37 : 41
38 : 41
39 : 41
40 : 41
41 : 41
42 : 41
43 : 41
44 : 41
45 : 41
46 : 41
47 : 41
48 : 41
49 : 41
50 : 41
51 : 41
52 : 61
53 : 61
54 : 61
55 : 61
56 : 61
57 : 61
58 : 61
59 : 61
60 : 61
61 : 61
62 : 61
63 : 61
64 : 61
65 : 61
66 : 61
67 : 71
68 : 71
69 : 71
70 : 71
71 : 71
72 : 71
73 : 71
74 : 71
75 : 71
76 : 71
77 : 71
78 : 71
79 : 71
80 : 71
81 : 71
82 : 71
83 : 71
84 : 71
85 : 71
86 : 71
87 : 71
88 : 71
89 : 71
90 : 71
91 : 71
92 : 71
93 : 71
94 : 71
95 : 71
96 : 71
97 : 71
98 : 71
99 : 71
100 : 71
```